# numpy.load from io.BytesIO stream

Tags: python, numpy, azure-storage

I have numpy arrays saved in Azure Blob Storage, and I'm loading them to a stream like this:

```
stream = io.BytesIO()
store.get_blob_to_stream(container, 'cat.npy', stream)
```

I know from `stream.getvalue()` that the stream contains the metadata to reconstruct the array. This is the first 150 bytes:

```
b"\x93NUMPY\x01\x00v\x00{'descr': '|u1', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (720, 1280, 3), }                                                  \n\xc1\xb0\x94\xc2\xb1\x95\xc3\xb2\x96\xc4\xb3\x97\xc5\xb4\x98\xc6\xb5\x99\xc7\xb6\x9a\xc7"
```

Is it possible to load the bytes stream with `numpy.load` or by some other simple method?

I could instead save the array to disk and load it from disk, but I'd like to avoid that for several reasons...

EDIT: just to emphasize, the output would need to be a numpy array with the shape and dtype specified in the 128 first bytes of the stream.

Comment: If you saved it to disk, how would you load it?

Comment: @hpaulj by `numpy.load()`

Comment: `load` accepts an open file like object.

Comment: ok yeah couldn't get that working...

Answer (score 4):

I tried to use several ways to realize your needs.

Here is my sample codes.

```
from azure.storage.blob.baseblobservice import BaseBlobService
import numpy as np

account_name = '<your account name>'
account_key = '<your account key>'
container_name = '<your container name>'
blob_name = '<your blob name>'

blob_service = BaseBlobService(
    account_name=account_name,
    account_key=account_key
)
```

Sample 1. To generate a blob url with sas token to get the content via `requests`

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobPermissions
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import requests

sas_token = blob_service.generate_blob_shared_access_signature(container_name, blob_name, permission=BlobPermissions.READ, expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1))
print(sas_token)
url_with_sas = blob_service.make_blob_url(container_name, blob_name, sas_token=sas_token)
print(url_with_sas)

r = requests.get(url_with_sas)
dat = np.frombuffer(r.content)
print('from requests', dat)
```

Sample 2. To download the content of blob into memory via `BytesIO`

```
import io
stream = io.BytesIO()
blob_service.get_blob_to_stream(container_name, blob_name, stream)
dat = np.frombuffer(stream.getbuffer())
print('from BytesIO', dat)
```

Sample 3. Use `numpy.fromfile` with [`DataSource`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.DataSource.html#numpy.DataSource) to open a blob url with sas token, it will actually download blob file into local filesystem.

```
ds = np.DataSource()
# ds = np.DataSource(None)  # use with temporary file
# ds = np.DataSource(path) # use with path like `data/`
f = ds.open(url_with_sas)
dat = np.fromfile(f)
print('from DataSource', dat)
```

I think Samples 1 & 2 are better for you.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the reply, but I guess I forgot to emphasize that I would specifically need a numpy array with the shape and dtype as in the `stream.getvalue()` first 128 bytes... `np.frombuffer(stream.read())` would actually work fine!

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to np.savez the above solution normally want work.

### Upload to storage:

```
import io    
import numpy as np    

stream = io.BytesIO()  
arr1 = np.random.rand(20,4)  
arr2 = np.random.rand(20,4)  
np.savez(stream, A=arr1, B=arr2)  
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_bytes(container, 
                                          "my/path.npz", 
                                          stream.getvalue())
```

### Download from storage:

```
from numpy.lib.npyio import NpzFile 

stream = io.BytesIO()  
block_blob_service.get_blob_to_stream(container, "my/path.npz", stream)  

ret = NpzFile(stream, own_fid=True, allow_pickle=True)  
print(ret.files)  
""" ['A', 'B'] """  
print(ret['A'].shape)  
""" (20, 4) """
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hacky way I came up with, which basically just gets the metadata from the first 128 bytes:

```
def load_npy_from_stream(stream_):
    """Experimental, may not work!

    :param stream_: io.BytesIO() object obtained by e.g. calling BlockBlobService().get_blob_to_stream() containing
        the binary stream of a standard format .npy file.
    :return: numpy.ndarray
    """
    stream_.seek(0)
    prefix_ = stream_.read(128)  # first 128 bytes seem to be the metadata
    dict_string = re.search('\{(.*?)\}', prefix_[1:].decode())[0]
    metadata_dict = eval(dict_string)

    array = np.frombuffer(stream_.read(), dtype=metadata_dict['descr']).reshape(metadata_dict['shape'])

    return array
```

Could fail in numerous ways, but I'm posting it here if anyone wants to give it a shot. I'll be running tests with this and will get back as I know more.

Answer (score 1):

A little late but in case anyone wants to do this using numpy.load, here's the code (Azure SDK v12.8.1):

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import io
import numpy as np

# define your connection parameters
connect_str = ''
container_name = ''
blob_name = ''

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)

blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name,
                                                  blob=blob_name)

# Get StorageStreamDownloader
blob_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
stream = io.BytesIO()
blob_stream.download_to_stream(stream)
stream.seek(0)

# Load form io.BytesIO object
data = np.load(stream, allow_pickle=False)

print(data.shape)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I guess it's the seek(0) that makes it work? allow_pickle=False seems to be the default.