# Is there any way to read numpy array in Azure Blob Storage in python?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, numpy-ndarray

I would like to read the numpy array stored in Azure Blob Storage from python code in Azure functions. I am not being able to do it. I tried with BlockBlobService but couldn't succeed.

Looking for help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to use Azure Storage SDK for Python to download the blob content to memory, then to use the function [`numpy.frombuffer`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.16/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) to load the memory content of the blob as a 1-dimensional array and continous to do any operations as you want like `reshape`.

As reference, there is a SO thread [numpy.load from io.BytesIO stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610891/numpy-load-from-io-bytesio-stream/55629510#55629510) that be same as yours and I answered it with three sample codes for loading `npy` or `npz` format content from blob.

If you want to read a csv/json file from Azure Blob Storage, you also can generate a blob url with sas token, then to use the function `pandas.read_csv` or `pandas.read_json` with an url parameter of `<blob url with sas token>` to directly read the content of csv or json format as a pandas dataframe and then to convert it to a numpy array.